# Does Apache Guacamole support VNC Connection with GNUTLS?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, remote-access, encryption, vnc

Currently I've working on my custom Remote Desktop Service which is strongly based on Apache Guacamole. I want my whole session encrypted with TLS when I enter Guacamole and connect to my PC with a TigerVNC server installed.

There are three connections that need to be covered with TLS;

First is HTTP Access to the Guacamole Page. Second is the connection Guacamole client and Guacamole Server. Last is Remote connection with guacd and remote protocol server within the target PC.

I have applied HTTPS to the Guacamole Web Page, so first section is completed encrypted. And also I have applied TLS to the Guacamole Client and guacd, by giving `guacd-ssl` option and certificate in guacamole.properties file. I referred to the following site : https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html

So for the last section, I found that I can encrypt VNC connection between Guacamole (which is actually LibVNCClient) and my TigerVNC Server with SSL/TLS,

So I built LibVNCServer with `-DWITH_GNUTLS=ON -DWITH_OPENSSL=OFF`option and installed Guacamole based on customed LibVNCServer.

Below is the generated log when I build LibVNCServer and Guacamole.

```
cmake -DWITH_OPENSSL=OFF -DWITH_GNUTLS=ON ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib64/libz.so (found version "1.2.7")
-- Found LZO: /usr/lib64/liblzo2.so
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so (found version "62")
-- Performing Test FOUND_LIBJPEG_TURBO
-- Performing Test FOUND_LIBJPEG_TURBO - Success
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib64/libpng.so (found version "1.5.13")
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found SDL2: /usr/lib64/libSDL2.so;-lpthread
-- Found GTK2_GTK: /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so
-- Found GnuTLS: /usr/lib64/libgnutls.so (found version "3.3.29")
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.27.1")
-- Checking for module 'libsystemd'
--   Found libsystemd, version 219
-- Found FFMPEG: /usr/include/ffmpeg (found suitable version "3.4.9", minimum required is "3.1.0") found components: avformat avcodec avutil swscale
-- Looking for dirent.h
-- Looking for dirent.h - found
-- Looking for endian.h
-- Looking for endian.h - found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for netinet/in.h
-- Looking for netinet/in.h - found
-- Looking for sys/endian.h
-- Looking for sys/endian.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/socket.h
-- Looking for sys/socket.h - found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for sys/time.h
-- Looking for sys/time.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for sys/wait.h
-- Looking for sys/wait.h - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - found
-- Looking for vfork.h
-- Looking for vfork.h - not found
-- Looking for ws2tcpip.h
-- Looking for ws2tcpip.h - not found
-- Looking for arpa/inet.h
-- Looking for arpa/inet.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for gettimeofday
-- Looking for gettimeofday - found
-- Looking for vfork
-- Looking for vfork - found
-- Looking for vprintf
-- Looking for vprintf - found
-- Looking for mmap
-- Looking for mmap - found
-- Looking for fork
-- Looking for fork - found
-- Looking for ftime
-- Looking for ftime - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for gethostname
-- Looking for gethostname - found
-- Looking for inet_ntoa
-- Looking for inet_ntoa - found
-- Looking for memmove
-- Looking for memmove - found
-- Looking for memset
-- Looking for memset - found
-- Looking for mkfifo
-- Looking for mkfifo - found
-- Looking for select
-- Looking for select - found
-- Looking for socket
-- Looking for socket - found
-- Looking for strchr
-- Looking for strchr - found
-- Looking for strcspn
-- Looking for strcspn - found
-- Looking for strdup
-- Looking for strdup - found
-- Looking for strerror
-- Looking for strerror - found
-- Looking for strstr
-- Looking for strstr - found
-- Looking for htobe64
-- Looking for htobe64 - found
-- Looking for OSSwapHostToBigInt64
-- Looking for OSSwapHostToBigInt64 - not found
-- Building crypto with builtin functions, only including SHA1 and D3DES
-- Threads support is using pthreads
-- Check size of pid_t
-- Check size of pid_t - done
-- Check size of size_t
-- Check size of size_t - done
-- Check size of socklen_t
-- Check size of socklen_t - done
-- Check size of in_addr_t
-- Check size of in_addr_t - done
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Searching 16 bit integer - Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Building TLS with GnuTLS
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /root/libvncserver/build
```

```
[root@localhost build]# cmake --build .
Scanning dependencies of target vncclient
[  1%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncclient.dir/libvncclient/cursor.c.o
[  2%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncclient.dir/libvncclient/listen.c.o
[  3%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncclient.dir/libvncclient/rfbproto.c.o
[  4%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncclient.dir/libvncclient/sockets.c.o
[  5%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncclient.dir/libvncclient/vncviewer.c.o
[  6%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncclient.dir/common/crypto_included.c.o
[  7%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncclient.dir/common/sha1.c.o
[  8%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncclient.dir/common/d3des.c.o
[  8%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncclient.dir/common/turbojpeg.c.o
[  9%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncclient.dir/libvncclient/tls_gnutls.c.o
[ 10%] Linking C shared library libvncclient.so
[ 10%] Built target vncclient
Scanning dependencies of target vncserver
[ 11%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/main.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/rfbserver.c.o
/root/libvncserver/libvncserver/rfbserver.c: In function ‘rfbProcessExtendedServerCutTextData’:
/root/libvncserver/libvncserver/rfbserver.c:2134:20: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
     stream.next_in = data;
                    ^
[ 13%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/rfbregion.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/auth.c.o
[ 15%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/sockets.c.o
[ 16%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/stats.c.o
[ 17%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/corre.c.o
[ 18%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/hextile.c.o
[ 19%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/rre.c.o
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/translate.c.o
[ 21%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/cutpaste.c.o
[ 21%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/httpd.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/cursor.c.o
[ 23%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/font.c.o
[ 24%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/draw.c.o
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/selbox.c.o
[ 26%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/common/vncauth.c.o
[ 27%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/cargs.c.o
[ 28%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/ultra.c.o
[ 29%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/scale.c.o
[ 30%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/common/crypto_included.c.o
[ 31%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/common/sha1.c.o
[ 32%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/common/d3des.c.o
[ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/rfbssl_gnutls.c.o
[ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/zlib.c.o
[ 34%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/zrle.c.o
[ 35%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/zrleoutstream.c.o
[ 36%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/zrlepalettehelper.c.o
[ 37%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/tight.c.o
[ 38%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/common/turbojpeg.c.o
[ 39%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/tightvnc-filetransfer/rfbtightserver.c.o
[ 40%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/tightvnc-filetransfer/handlefiletransferrequest.c.o
[ 41%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/tightvnc-filetransfer/filetransfermsg.c.o
[ 42%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/tightvnc-filetransfer/filelistinfo.c.o
[ 43%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/websockets.c.o
[ 44%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/libvncserver/ws_decode.c.o
[ 45%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vncserver.dir/common/base64.c.o
[ 46%] Linking C shared library libvncserver.so
[ 46%] Built target vncserver
Scanning dependencies of target test_tjbench
[ 47%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_tjbench.dir/test/tjbench.c.o
[ 48%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_tjbench.dir/test/tjutil.c.o
[ 49%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_tjbench.dir/test/bmp.c.o
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_tjbench.dir/common/turbojpeg.c.o
[ 51%] Linking C executable test/tjbench
[ 51%] Built target test_tjbench
Scanning dependencies of target test_copyrecttest
[ 52%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_copyrecttest.dir/test/copyrecttest.c.o
[ 53%] Linking C executable test/copyrecttest
[ 53%] Built target test_copyrecttest
Scanning dependencies of target test_cargstest
[ 54%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_cargstest.dir/test/cargstest.c.o
[ 55%] Linking C executable test/cargstest
[ 55%] Built target test_cargstest
Scanning dependencies of target client_examples_gtkvncviewer
[ 56%] Building C object CMakeFiles/client_examples_gtkvncviewer.dir/client_examples/gtkvncviewer.c.o
[ 57%] Linking C executable client_examples/gtkvncviewer
[ 57%] Built target client_examples_gtkvncviewer
Scanning dependencies of target test_wstest
[ 58%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_wstest.dir/test/wstest.c.o
[ 59%] Linking C executable test/wstest
[ 59%] Built target test_wstest
Scanning dependencies of target examples_fontsel
[ 60%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_fontsel.dir/examples/fontsel.c.o
[ 61%] Linking C executable examples/fontsel
[ 61%] Built target examples_fontsel
Scanning dependencies of target examples_pnmshow24
[ 62%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_pnmshow24.dir/examples/pnmshow24.c.o
[ 62%] Linking C executable examples/pnmshow24
[ 62%] Built target examples_pnmshow24
Scanning dependencies of target copy-compile-commands
[ 62%] Built target copy-compile-commands
Scanning dependencies of target examples_regiontest
[ 63%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_regiontest.dir/examples/regiontest.c.o
[ 64%] Linking C executable examples/regiontest
[ 64%] Built target examples_regiontest
Scanning dependencies of target examples_cursors
[ 65%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_cursors.dir/examples/cursors.c.o
[ 66%] Linking C executable examples/cursors
[ 66%] Built target examples_cursors
Scanning dependencies of target examples_camera
[ 67%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_camera.dir/examples/camera.c.o
[ 67%] Linking C executable examples/camera
[ 67%] Built target examples_camera
Scanning dependencies of target examples_backchannel
[ 68%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_backchannel.dir/examples/backchannel.c.o
[ 69%] Linking C executable examples/backchannel
[ 69%] Built target examples_backchannel
Scanning dependencies of target examples_vncev
[ 69%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_vncev.dir/examples/vncev.c.o
[ 70%] Linking C executable examples/vncev
[ 70%] Built target examples_vncev
Scanning dependencies of target client_examples_SDLvncviewer
[ 70%] Building C object CMakeFiles/client_examples_SDLvncviewer.dir/client_examples/SDLvncviewer.c.o
[ 71%] Linking C executable client_examples/SDLvncviewer
[ 71%] Built target client_examples_SDLvncviewer
Scanning dependencies of target examples_pnmshow
[ 72%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_pnmshow.dir/examples/pnmshow.c.o
[ 73%] Linking C executable examples/pnmshow
[ 73%] Built target examples_pnmshow
Scanning dependencies of target examples_colourmaptest
[ 74%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_colourmaptest.dir/examples/colourmaptest.c.o
[ 75%] Linking C executable examples/colourmaptest
[ 75%] Built target examples_colourmaptest
Scanning dependencies of target test_encodingstest
[ 76%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_encodingstest.dir/test/encodingstest.c.o
[ 77%] Linking C executable test/encodingstest
[ 77%] Built target test_encodingstest
Scanning dependencies of target examples_example
[ 78%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_example.dir/examples/example.c.o
[ 79%] Linking C executable examples/example
[ 79%] Built target examples_example
Scanning dependencies of target examples_blooptest
[ 80%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_blooptest.dir/examples/blooptest.c.o
[ 81%] Linking C executable examples/blooptest
[ 81%] Built target examples_blooptest
Scanning dependencies of target examples_repeater
[ 82%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_repeater.dir/examples/repeater.c.o
[ 83%] Linking C executable examples/repeater
[ 83%] Built target examples_repeater
Scanning dependencies of target test_tjunittest
[ 84%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_tjunittest.dir/test/tjunittest.c.o
[ 84%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_tjunittest.dir/test/tjutil.c.o
[ 85%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_tjunittest.dir/common/turbojpeg.c.o
[ 86%] Linking C executable test/tjunittest
[ 86%] Built target test_tjunittest
Scanning dependencies of target examples_rotate
[ 87%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_rotate.dir/examples/rotate.c.o
[ 88%] Linking C executable examples/rotate
[ 88%] Built target examples_rotate
Scanning dependencies of target examples_simple
[ 89%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_simple.dir/examples/simple.c.o
[ 90%] Linking C executable examples/simple
[ 90%] Built target examples_simple
Scanning dependencies of target examples_simple15
[ 91%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_simple15.dir/examples/simple15.c.o
[ 92%] Linking C executable examples/simple15
[ 92%] Built target examples_simple15
Scanning dependencies of target examples_storepasswd
[ 93%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_storepasswd.dir/examples/storepasswd.c.o
[ 94%] Linking C executable examples/storepasswd
[ 94%] Built target examples_storepasswd
Scanning dependencies of target examples_filetransfer
[ 95%] Building C object CMakeFiles/examples_filetransfer.dir/examples/filetransfer.c.o
[ 96%] Linking C executable examples/filetransfer
[ 96%] Built target examples_filetransfer
Scanning dependencies of target client_examples_backchannel
[ 97%] Building C object CMakeFiles/client_examples_backchannel.dir/client_examples/backchannel.c.o
[ 98%] Linking C executable client_examples/backchannel
[ 98%] Built target client_examples_backchannel
Scanning dependencies of target client_examples_ppmtest
[ 99%] Building C object CMakeFiles/client_examples_ppmtest.dir/client_examples/ppmtest.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable client_examples/ppmtest
[100%] Built target client_examples_ppmtest

[root@localhost build]# make
[ 10%] Built target vncclient
[ 46%] Built target vncserver
[ 51%] Built target test_tjbench
[ 53%] Built target test_copyrecttest
[ 55%] Built target test_cargstest
[ 57%] Built target client_examples_gtkvncviewer
[ 59%] Built target test_wstest
[ 61%] Built target examples_fontsel
[ 62%] Built target examples_pnmshow24
[ 62%] Built target copy-compile-commands
[ 64%] Built target examples_regiontest
[ 66%] Built target examples_cursors
[ 67%] Built target examples_camera
[ 69%] Built target examples_backchannel
[ 70%] Built target examples_vncev
[ 71%] Built target client_examples_SDLvncviewer
[ 73%] Built target examples_pnmshow
[ 75%] Built target examples_colourmaptest
[ 77%] Built target test_encodingstest
[ 79%] Built target examples_example
[ 81%] Built target examples_blooptest
[ 83%] Built target examples_repeater
[ 86%] Built target test_tjunittest
[ 88%] Built target examples_rotate
[ 90%] Built target examples_simple
[ 92%] Built target examples_simple15
[ 94%] Built target examples_storepasswd
[ 96%] Built target examples_filetransfer
[ 98%] Built target client_examples_backchannel
[100%] Built target client_examples_ppmtest

[root@localhost build]# make test
Running tests...
Test project /root/libvncserver/build
    Start 1: cargs
1/4 Test #1: cargs ............................   Passed    0.01 sec
    Start 2: includetest
2/4 Test #2: includetest ......................   Passed    0.62 sec
    Start 3: turbojpeg
3/4 Test #3: turbojpeg ........................   Passed    6.17 sec
    Start 4: wstest
4/4 Test #4: wstest ...........................   Passed    0.01 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 4

Total Test time (real) =   6.82 sec

[root@localhost build]# make install
[ 10%] Built target vncclient
[ 46%] Built target vncserver
[ 51%] Built target test_tjbench
[ 53%] Built target test_copyrecttest
[ 55%] Built target test_cargstest
[ 57%] Built target client_examples_gtkvncviewer
[ 59%] Built target test_wstest
[ 61%] Built target examples_fontsel
[ 62%] Built target examples_pnmshow24
[ 62%] Built target copy-compile-commands
[ 64%] Built target examples_regiontest
[ 66%] Built target examples_cursors
[ 67%] Built target examples_camera
[ 69%] Built target examples_backchannel
[ 70%] Built target examples_vncev
[ 71%] Built target client_examples_SDLvncviewer
[ 73%] Built target examples_pnmshow
[ 75%] Built target examples_colourmaptest
[ 77%] Built target test_encodingstest
[ 79%] Built target examples_example
[ 81%] Built target examples_blooptest
[ 83%] Built target examples_repeater
[ 86%] Built target test_tjunittest
[ 88%] Built target examples_rotate
[ 90%] Built target examples_simple
[ 92%] Built target examples_simple15
[ 94%] Built target examples_storepasswd
[ 96%] Built target examples_filetransfer
[ 98%] Built target client_examples_backchannel
[100%] Built target client_examples_ppmtest
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libvncclient.so.0.9.13
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib64/libvncclient.so.1
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib64/libvncclient.so
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/rfb/keysym.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/rfb/threading.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/rfb/rfb.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/rfb/rfbclient.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/rfb/rfbconfig.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/rfb/rfbproto.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/rfb/rfbregion.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libvncserver.so.0.9.13
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib64/libvncserver.so.1
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib64/libvncserver.so
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/rfb/keysym.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/rfb/threading.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/rfb/rfb.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/rfb/rfbclient.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/rfb/rfbconfig.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/rfb/rfbproto.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/rfb/rfbregion.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/cmake/LibVNCServer/LibVNCServerTargets.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/cmake/LibVNCServer/LibVNCServerTargets-noconfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/cmake/LibVNCServer/LibVNCServerConfigVersion.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/cmake/LibVNCServer/LibVNCServerConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/libvncserver.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/libvncclient.pc
```

```
------------------------------------------------
guacamole-server version 1.2.0
------------------------------------------------

   Library status:

     freerdp2 ............ yes
     pango ............... yes
     libavcodec .......... yes
     libavformat.......... yes
     libavutil ........... yes
     libssh2 ............. yes
     libssl .............. yes
     libswscale .......... yes
     libtelnet ........... yes
     libVNCServer ........ yes
     libvorbis ........... yes
     libpulse ............ yes
     libwebsockets ....... yes
     libwebp ............. yes
     wsock32 ............. no

   Protocol support:

      Kubernetes .... yes
      RDP ........... yes
      SSH ........... yes
      Telnet ........ yes
      Rlogin ........ yes
      VNC ........... yes

   Services / tools:

      guacd ...... yes
      guacenc .... yes
      guaclog .... yes

   FreeRDP plugins: /usr/lib64/freerdp2
   Init scripts: /etc/init.d
   Systemd units: no

Type "make" to compile guacamole-server.
```

Below is guacd log when I try to connect TigerVNC Server via Guacamole.

```
Jan 13 17:33:42 localhost guacd[19563]: Creating new client for protocol "vnc"
Jan 13 17:33:42 localhost guacd[19563]: Connection ID is "$83a2d4dd-24cc-441a-af1e-66a0e429639c"
Jan 13 17:33:42 localhost guacd[31041]: Cursor rendering: local
Jan 13 17:33:42 localhost guacd[31041]: User "@9cdcd7df-1d51-498f-bb4b-2399d1a1b8de" joined connection "$83a2d4dd-24cc-441a-af1e-66a0e429639c" (1 users now present)
Jan 13 17:33:42 localhost guacd[31041]: VNC server supports protocol version 3.8 (viewer 3.8)
Jan 13 17:33:42 localhost guacd[31041]: We have 2 security types to read
Jan 13 17:33:42 localhost guacd[31041]: 0) Received security type 19
Jan 13 17:33:42 localhost guacd[31041]: Selecting security type 19 (0/2 in the list)
Jan 13 17:33:42 localhost guacd[31041]: 1) Received security type 19
Jan 13 17:33:42 localhost guacd[31041]: Selected Security Scheme 19
Jan 13 17:33:42 localhost guacd[31041]: TLS is not supported.
Jan 13 17:33:42 localhost guacd[31041]: Connect failed. Waiting 1000ms before retrying...
Jan 13 17:33:43 localhost guacd[31041]: VNC server supports protocol version 3.8 (viewer 3.8)
Jan 13 17:33:43 localhost guacd[31041]: We have 2 security types to read
Jan 13 17:33:43 localhost guacd[31041]: 0) Received security type 19
Jan 13 17:33:43 localhost guacd[31041]: Selecting security type 19 (0/2 in the list)
Jan 13 17:33:43 localhost guacd[31041]: 1) Received security type 19
Jan 13 17:33:43 localhost guacd[31041]: Selected Security Scheme 19
Jan 13 17:33:43 localhost guacd[31041]: TLS is not supported.
Jan 13 17:33:43 localhost guacd[31041]: Connect failed. Waiting 1000ms before retrying...
Jan 13 17:33:44 localhost guacd[31041]: VNC server supports protocol version 3.8 (viewer 3.8)
Jan 13 17:33:44 localhost guacd[31041]: We have 2 security types to read
Jan 13 17:33:44 localhost guacd[31041]: 0) Received security type 19
Jan 13 17:33:44 localhost guacd[31041]: Selecting security type 19 (0/2 in the list)
Jan 13 17:33:44 localhost guacd[31041]: 1) Received security type 19
Jan 13 17:33:44 localhost guacd[31041]: Selected Security Scheme 19
Jan 13 17:33:44 localhost guacd[31041]: TLS is not supported.
Jan 13 17:33:44 localhost guacd[31041]: Connect failed. Waiting 1000ms before retrying...
Jan 13 17:33:45 localhost guacd[31041]: VNC server supports protocol version 3.8 (viewer 3.8)
Jan 13 17:33:45 localhost guacd[31041]: We have 2 security types to read
Jan 13 17:33:45 localhost guacd[31041]: 0) Received security type 19
Jan 13 17:33:45 localhost guacd[31041]: Selecting security type 19 (0/2 in the list)
Jan 13 17:33:45 localhost guacd[31041]: 1) Received security type 19
Jan 13 17:33:45 localhost guacd[31041]: Selected Security Scheme 19
Jan 13 17:33:45 localhost guacd[31041]: TLS is not supported.
Jan 13 17:33:45 localhost guacd[31041]: Unable to connect to VNC server.
Jan 13 17:33:45 localhost guacd[31041]: User "@9cdcd7df-1d51-498f-bb4b-2399d1a1b8de" disconnected (0 users remain)
Jan 13 17:33:45 localhost guacd[31041]: Last user of connection "$83a2d4dd-24cc-441a-af1e-66a0e429639c" disconnected
Jan 13 17:33:47 localhost guacd[19563]: Connection "$83a2d4dd-24cc-441a-af1e-66a0e429639c" removed.
```

I cannot find any error log during make and make install.
LibVNCClient fully supports TLS with VeNCrypt, while LibVNCServer cannot. But I don't think Guacamole uses LibVNCServer.

Does Guacamole with LibVNCClient not support VeNCrypt encryption to the TigerVNC? What can I do further for encrypting my VNC connection?